# How to set timeout for exclusive lock in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have an import script that was failing because of the 'Exclusive nowait' option I set my script. This caused the script to error out the first time it could not get the exclusive lock on the table. My script did it this way:

"LOCK TABLE %s IN EXCLUSIVE MODE NOWAIT"

Now my script works it's just that I want to be able to set the timeout for PostgreSQL instead of having it wait for the maximum time which is 15mins. I prefer to set it in posgresql.conf. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What about trying to use the LOCK NOWAIT and if it fails, try that once again and again?

Answer (score 2):

This topic was [under discussion](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2010-08/msg00048.php) in August 2010, and at seems the patch which provided exactly the optin you need (lock_timeout) is about to be rejected because it complicates the timeout framework in PG to much. So I assume you have to go with the usual statement_timeout here.

Comment: Note: `lock_timeout` is available since PostgreSQL 9.3 - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-LOCK-TIMEOUT